# Why is the sin of n times pi always 0

Tags: trigonometry, roots, graphing-functions, pi

My instructor says that $\sin(\pi \cdot n)$ is always equal to $0$.

However, when playing with [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com), I find that this is not the case.

```
Math.sin(10000000000000000000 * Math.PI)
=> 0.7463367130158111
```

We get some random values, the more numbers we play with

```
Math.sin(100000000000000000000000 * Math.PI)
=> -0.7965162588457233
```

It doesn't look like there is any rule we can plug in for multiplying an integer by $\pi$.

I'm working with JavaScript, where the number $\pi$ is defined as

```
3.141592653589793
```

Does this have to do with their value of $\pi$ being inaccurate, as it only has around 15 digits. Is this not the true value of $\pi$?

In the above examples, I gave, would those evaluate to 0?

I'm skeptical of the $\sin(\pi \cdot n) = 0$ theory.

Comment: This is a because of the limited accuracy of numbers in programming languages. Please recall the *definition* of $\sin$.

Comment: This is just an error caused by using an approximation to $\pi$.  $sin(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. And  $sin(0)=0=sin(\pi)$ so $sin(n\pi)=0\;\forall n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: quite naturally it is because of precision. By definition of the sine function,we have that $sin(n\pi) = 0$ for all integers $n$, so the only thing that could affect your answer, since the sine function is defined correctly, is the precision. Of course, $\pi$ is irrational, hence you need a non-recurring non-terminating decimal to represent it correctly. 3.141592653589793 is just a 15 digit approximation to that, which is why your operation is failing for high values of $n$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a great question.

Comment: I don't know as I'd go so far as to say "great", but it certainly is worthwhile and even if the explanation is obvious to some, it does not deserve to be downvoted, in my opinion.  (On the other hand, that's why they're votes.)

Comment: @MJD I suppose some may find the title (and the last sentence especially) misplaced. I personally don't think it's an issue meriting downvotes but this is just my best guess.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong.  It appears you mean to say $\sin(n \pi)=0$.  You have lost the $\sin$ function in the first and last lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler of `jsconsole.com` handles these huge values using floating point numbers, and floating point loses precision when the exponent is large.

You can check that $\sin n\pi$ is near $0$(again not equal to $0$ due to floating point precision) for "small" values of $n$. This fact continues to hold for larger $n$ since $\sin$ is periodic. That is, $\sin x = \sin (x + 2\pi)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The value of $\pi$ is hard coded into Javascript as a double floating point number. There is no way to store the "true" value of $\pi$.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20(10000000000000000000000%20*%20pi)) is a site to check when you want to challenge the compiler using huge numbers.

Comment: So no computer could ever store the correct value of $pi$ because it can't be stored. And when dealing with large inputs, it could show up as something closer to $1$. So, since it can't be calculated or stored, we can't trust these calculations because they are only approximations. And with a wide range, the values will fluctuate widely. So basically, any calculations with $pi$, we shouldn't trust the computer?

Comment: @RichardHamilton Calculations that deal with reasonably small numbers may have a precision, and the true value is guaranteed to be around the computer generated value.

Comment: You've got the general idea: floating point computations need to be treated with suspicion. In practice the standards for floating point number representations and mathematical functions on them do let you write code that can be trusted to within a specified tolerance, but this requires an analysis of the range of the input data and of the calculations you are going to perform on it.

Comment: *Everything* is an approximation in computers and approximations within 15 decimal places is fine.  If you think about it the answer of .7 was only off but .7 which cosidering the input was 31415926535897932384 thats a margin of error of .7/31415926535897932384 or .000000000000000000002%.  That's pretty effing good.  Dont distrust the results.  Distrust the method that chose the input and the way of calculating the results.  3.141592653589793 is much closer to pi then 25.72 miles on google maps is close to the actual 25.72 miles.  *Much* closer.

Comment: @RichardHamilton It would also depend on how the computer is implementing the calculation of $\sin x$ as well as the storage of $\pi$. There are no explicit standards for how these are handled with large inputs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665418/standard-for-the-sine-of-very-large-numbers

Answer (score 1):

As far as *why* sine is always $0$ for $n\pi\;|\;n\in\Bbb Z$, go back to your unit circle. At $\theta=0$, the $y$ value is $0$. At $\pi$, on the opposite side of the circle, it's once again $0$. The same for $2\pi$, $3\pi$, etc.